# One directional access to the clipboard (OS to Emacs: no, Emacs to OS: yes)

Tags: copy-paste, clipboard

Is it possible that Emacs ignores the system clipboard?
I mean when outside of Emacs I copy something, Emacs ignores it.
But not vice-versa, i.e., I would like to be able to have the access to the content of Emacs kill ring when I work in an external program (i.e. notapad). To be precise, the question is related to Microsoft Windows, but it is relavant for ther OS's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
(setq interprogram-paste-function nil)
```